# Why quaternary nitrogen but not tertiary oxygen?

Tags: acid-base, ions, stability

Why do [quaternary ammonium ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_ammonium_cation) with a partially positive nitrogen form fairly readily and are often stable but tertiary oxygens, apparently called [oxonium ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxonium_ion), are more rare/less stable? The trend seems to continue down the periodic table, too, with phosphonium and sulfonium.

Comment: Short answer could be that ethers are weaker nuclophiles and better leaving groups then amines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the electronegativity of the species and how good of a base (or how good an acid the conjugate acids) are.

$\hspace{9ex}$ [image: H3O+]

$\hspace{7ex}$ [image]

[[source](http://cactus.dixie.edu/smblack/chem2310/summary_pages/pKa_chart.pdf)]

To put this in perspective, nitric acid ($\ce{HNO3}$) has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $-1.3$. Yes, $\ce{HNO3}$, a strong acid, is more stable than $\ce{H3O+}$! The central oxygen in $\ce{H3O+}$ is too electronegative to effectively share these electrons and form a stable bond. In $\ce{NH4+}$, its lone pairs are far more available due to nitrogen's lower electronegativity.

How common each species is only has to do with the number of acids stronger than $\ce{H3O+}$ or $\ce{NH4+}$. As you can imagine, there are going to be a lot more acids stronger than $\ce{NH4+}$, which starts out around the middle of the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ spectrum, than compared to $\ce{H3O+}$, which is near the end.

Answer (score 2):

The electronegativity of Oxygen is higher than Nitrogen, so it is much less suited for holding a positive charge, which, in turn leads to Mithoron's comment about weaker nucleophilicity and better leaving group ability.